# Creating a datatable with only the rows that match a specific column name prefix using Linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

For example my datatable is like this

A_1  A_2  A_3 ..... A_15 B_1.....B_10 C_1....C_10
x    y    z........ K
1    2    3.........4

I am trying to create seperate datatables for A,B and C which selects the rows based on column prefix, Also i just need row values in my new datatable.

```
var query = (from dc in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
             where dc.ColumnName.Contains(prefix)
             select table.Rows);
```

If the above is correct, how to proceed to insert the rows(which is in the query) to the new data table ?

Comment: This question seems incomprehensible to me. It seems like you are asking for someone to complete your code to accomplish what you want. Maybe showing the code that you have tried will help to explain the question better.

Comment: I think your query won't work as your 'select' statement is wrong.... you are selecting the rows from 'table'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `DataView` then copy to a `DataTable` selecting the columns that match your criteria:

```
string[] cols = (from dc in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                 where dc.ColumnName.Contains(prefix)
                 select dc.ColumnName)
                .ToArray();

DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable selected = view.ToTable(false, cols); // false ==> include "duplicate" rows
```

Comment: Thanks much this one helped!